# Java Console based Client - Server login application - error in Database authentication

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, resultset

I've been trying to resolve this issue since morning. I have client and server applications, client sends user name and password, server receives it, checks in database, sends a message success to the right user.
But, I'm unable to process this request from client side.
What's the problem and where's its lying ? 
Awaiting experts solutions...

Here is the Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;

class TCPServer
{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
       {
          String clientSentence,clientpassword;
          String capitalizedSentence;
          ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(4003);
          Connection con = null;
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
          String db = "database";
          String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
          String user = "root";
          String pass = "root";

          while(true)
          {
             Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
             BufferedReader inFromClient =
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
             BufferedReader inFromClient1 =
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
             DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
             clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine(); 
             clientpassword = inFromClient.readLine();
             System.out.println("Received User Name: " + clientSentence);
             System.out.println("Received Password: " + clientpassword);
             Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, user, pass);
             Statement st = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  table WHERE user='clientSentence' AND password='clientpassword'");
             while (res.next()) { 
             String u = res.getString("user");
             String p = res.getString("password");
             if (clientSentence.equals(u) && clientpassword.equals(p)){
             capitalizedSentence = "Welcome "+clientSentence+" \n";
             outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence); 
            }else{  
             capitalizedSentence = "Sorry, not authorized \n";
             outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence); 
            }    
          }
        }con.close();
       }
}
```

and the Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TCPClient
{
  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
  {
   String sentence,sentence1;
   String modifiedSentence;
   BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   BufferedReader inFromUser1 = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4003);
   DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
   DataOutputStream outToServer1 = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
   BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
   Console console = System.console();
   String username = console.readLine("Enter your Username :");
   char pswd[] = console.readPassword("Enter your Password :");
   String upwd=new String(pswd);
   outToServer.writeBytes(username + '\n');
   outToServer1.writeBytes(upwd + '\n');
   modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
   System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
}
   clientSocket.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when running your code or you just don't get the expected result ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu , No errors. I do not get reply from the server. Both get to freeze!

Comment: But I did not get any NPE ? i have one more doubt, my client just ends when I get get success message or sorry message from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code results in a `NullPointerException` in `TCPClient` if you don't have a `Console` associated with your JVM.

---

> ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  table WHERE user='clientSentence' AND password='clientpassword'");

That is definitely not going to work unless you really want to always use the username 'clientSentence' and the password 'clientpassword'.

You should pass the actual value of the corresponding java variables that you set above that line. Also, the right approach for this is to use a `PreparedStatement` and pass the user input as arguments, so that the driver will take care of sanitizing the input in order to avoid SQL injection or errors like `ImbecilUserException`. :)

Comment: Actual value ? , I am passing the actual values of variables :


`ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  table WHERE user='clientSentence' AND password='clientpassword'");`

Here clientSentence and clientpassword are corresponding java variables. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: They are NOT. They're just literal strings; you need something like: `... WHERE user = '" + clientSentence + "' AND password = '" + clientpassword + "'...");`. The right way, however, is to use a `PreparedStatement` as I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the client and server on the same machine, you shoudn't be using the same port for the client and server sockets.. use different ports..

Comment: +1 for the suggestion. In fact, it is always preferable to have different ports for server and client, irrespective of whether you're working on the same machine or not

Comment: Thank you for the replies. WHat do you mean different ports ? If we change ports, how does client and server communicate !? Clarify me in which regard you are saying like this..

Comment: According to the javadoc, that `Socket` constructor "Creates a stream socket and connects it to the specified port number on the named host". So that port number is actually the server port, not the client port, which remains unspecified.